# Android TextView comes up null in SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, listview, listactivity, simplecursoradapter

I'm using a SimpleCursorAdapter and for some reason sometimes the `findViewById` method returns null to some of the TextViews. The id's correspond to the XML Layout widgets. Any ideas as to why?

This is the OrderList.java where I have the SimpleCursorAdapter:

```
package com.orderdelivery;


import java.util.ArrayList;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.ListActivity;
 import android.app.ProgressDialog;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.database.Cursor;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.ContextMenu;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.MenuInflater;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
 import android.view.View.OnLongClickListener;
 import android.widget.AdapterView;
 import android.widget.AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo;
 import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
 import android.widget.ListView;
 import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import com.orderdelivery.DataAdapter;

 public class OrderList extends ListActivity {
private ListView list;
ArrayList<Order> orders;
OrderListAdapter oAdapter;
SimpleOrderAdapter oCursorAdapter;
private Runnable viewOrders;
private ProgressDialog progress=null;
private DataAdapter dbAdapter;
private int[] views;
private String[] columns;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {



    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    list = getListView();
    //  list.setAdapter(oCursorAdapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int   arg2,long arg3) 
        {
            Cursor cursor = (Cursor) list.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
            Intent intent = new    Intent("com.orderdelivery.GROCERYITEMLIST");
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            intent.putExtra("order_id", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("order_id")));


            startActivity(intent);
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        }
    );

    registerForContextMenu(getListView());

      list.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener(){

            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                return false;
            }});

    //        orders = new ArrayList<Order>();
    //        
    //        for(int i =0; i<5;i++){
    //          orders.add(new Order("19995","Pueblo, Maya",i,"Pending", null, null, null)); //Customer, items, confirmation...
    //        }
    //        
    //        oAdapter = new OrderListAdapter(this,R.layout.row,orders);
    //        list.setAdapter(oAdapter);
    //       
    dbAdapter = new DataAdapter(this);
    dbAdapter.open();
    dbAdapter.deleteAll();

    columns = new String[] {"order_id","retailer_name","qty","status"};
    views = new int[]{R.id.orderNumber,R.id.location,R.id.quantity,R.id.status};


    oCursorAdapter = new SimpleOrderAdapter(this,R.layout.row,dbAdapter.getAllOrders(),columns,views);
    list.setAdapter(oCursorAdapter);

    // Cursor oCursor = dbAdapter.getAllOrders();


        viewOrders = new Runnable(){

            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                updateData();
                runOnUiThread(returnRes);
            }

        };

        Thread thread = new Thread(viewOrders,"getOrderThread");
        progress = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Please wait...","Retrieving assigned orders...", true);
        thread.start();


}

private Runnable returnRes = new Runnable(){

    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        oCursorAdapter.changeCursorAndColumns(dbAdapter.getAllOrders(), columns, views);

        oCursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        progress.dismiss();
    }

};


private void updateData(){


    dbAdapter.addOrder("1995", "Pending", "100101", 12, 31, "Pueblo,Xtra", "Mayaguez" , 1);
    dbAdapter.addOrder("1991", "Pending", "100102", 12, 31, "Pueblo,Xtra", "Mayaguez" , 1);
    dbAdapter.addOrder("1993", "Pending", "100103", 12, 31, "Pueblo,Xtra", "Mayaguez" , 1);
    dbAdapter.addCustomer("1995", "Robert Soler", "Urb. Villa Mofongo II3", "PR", "Mayaguez", "00617", "787-391-5555", "787-391-5555");
    dbAdapter.addCustomer("1991", "Robert Soler", "Urb. Villa Mofongo II3", "PR", "Mayaguez", "00617", "787-391-5555", "787-391-5555");
    dbAdapter.addCustomer("1993", "Robert Soler", "Urb. Villa Mofongo II3", "PR", "Mayaguez", "00617", "787-391-5555", "787-391-5555");
    dbAdapter.addItem("0101", "Habichuelas Blancas", "1995", "Si es GOYA tiene que ser bueno", 1, "Goya", 0, 2.75, "1001019");
    dbAdapter.addItem("0102", "Honey Nut Cheerios", "1995", "Cereal Cheerios", 5, "General Mills", 0, 3.99, "10019876");
    dbAdapter.addItem("0111", "Habichuelas Rosadas", "1995", "Si es GOYA tiene que ser bueno", 1, "Goya", 0, 2.75, "1001019");
    dbAdapter.addItem("0112", "Arroz Rico", "1995", "Rico", 5, "Bien, Bien Rico", 0, 3.99, "10019876");
    dbAdapter.addItem("0121", "Habichuelas Blancas", "1991", "Si es GOYA tiene que ser bueno", 1, "Goya", 0, 2.75, "1001019");
    dbAdapter.addItem("0122", "Honey Nut Cheerios", "1991", "Cereal Cheerios", 5, "General Mills", 0, 3.99, "10019876");
    dbAdapter.addItem("0131", "Habichuelas Blancas", "1993", "Si es GOYA tiene que ser bueno", 1, "Goya", 0, 2.75, "1001019");
    dbAdapter.addItem("0132", "Honey Nut Cheerios", "1993", "Cereal Cheerios", 5, "General Mills", 0, 3.99, "10019876");



}






private class OrderListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Order> {

    private ArrayList<Order> orders;

    private OrderListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Order> orders)
    {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, orders);
        this.orders = orders;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v==null)
        {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        }

        Order o = orders.get(position);
        if(o!=null){

            TextView orderNum = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.orderNumber);
            TextView location = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.location);
            TextView quantity = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
            TextView status = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.status);

            if(orderNum!=null){
                orderNum.setText("Order " + o.getOrderNumber());
            }

            if(location!=null)
            {
                location.setText("Location: "+o.getOrderRetailer());
            }

            if(quantity!=null){
                quantity.setText("Qty: "+o.getTotalQuantity());

            }

            if(status!=null){
                status.setText("Status: "+ o.getStatus());
            }

        }

        return v;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    Intent intent = new Intent("com.orderdelivery.GROCERYITEMLIST");

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    bundle.putInt("position", position);


}

//Might be needed
public static Order getOrderAtPosition(int pos){

    return null;

}
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.item_menu, menu);   
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //Como obtener el item de la lista a desplegar!!!
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

    //test
    switch (item.getItemId()){

    case R.id.itemMenu_details:

        Intent in = new Intent("com.orderdelivery.GROCERYORDERDETAILS");
        Bundle bund = new Bundle();
        /*
        this.listCursorAdapter.getCursor().moveToFirst();
        int position =     this.listCursorAdapter.getCursor().getColumnIndex(DataAdapter.ITEM_KEY_ORDER_ID);
        String orderId =    this.listCursorAdapter.getCursor().getString(position);
        */

        String orderId =   "1995";//this.listCursorAdapter.getCursor().getString(2);

        bund.putString("order_id", orderId);
        in.putExtras(bund);
        startActivity(in);

        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}    

private class SimpleOrderAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public SimpleOrderAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
            String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.bindView(v, context, c);
        TextView orderNum = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.orderNumber);
        TextView location = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.location);
        TextView quantity = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
        TextView status = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.status);

        String orderNumString="Order "+ c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DataAdapter.ORDER_KEY_ORDER_ID));
        String    locationString=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DataAdapter.ORDER_KEY_RETAILER));
        int qty = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DataAdapter.ORDER_KEY_QTY));

        String statusString =      c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DataAdapter.ORDER_KEY_STATUS));

        orderNum.setText(orderNumString);
        location.setText(locationString);
        quantity.setText(""+qty); //FIXXX
        status.setText(statusString);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor c, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);


        TextView orderNum = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.orderNumber);
        TextView location = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.location);
        TextView quantity = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
        TextView status = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.status);

        String orderNumString="Order "+     c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DataAdapter.ORDER_KEY_ORDER_ID));
        String locationString="Location:        "+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DataAdapter.ORDER_KEY_RETAILER));
        String qtyString ="Qty: "+     c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DataAdapter.ORDER_KEY_QTY));
        String statusString = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DataAdapter.ORDER_KEY_STATUS));

        orderNum.setText(orderNumString);
        location.setText(locationString);
        quantity.setText(qtyString);
        status.setText(statusString);
        return v;



    }




    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the xml files as well?

Comment: I have similar problem, I have posted the question in another post, can some one please look into it.... thank you in advance....:)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053892/simplecursoradapter-textview-giving-nullpointerexception cheers,
raj