# simplecursoradapter textview giving nullpointerexception

Tags: android, android-listview, nullpointerexception, textview, simplecursoradapter

I have two xml files one is having the listview and another is having the layout of the listview vth some texviews, I want to change the color of the textview in the second xml file. This is what i have done so far.

main1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="4px">

    <ListView droid:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/header"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_control_bar1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="45dip"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

opp_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="8px">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lastName"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6px"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/firstName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/firstName"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/total"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8px"
        android:textColor="@color/closedDate" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

opp.java:

```
public class OppMain extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    final String tag = "output";
    static String Header = "Opportunities";
    static String DBName, Date = null;
    protected Cursor cursor;
    protected ListAdapter adapter;
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main1);

        TextView hdr = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.header);
        hdr.setText(Header);

        //database              
        db = (new openDataBaseAdapter(this)).getWritableDatabase();
        cursor = db.query("userdata", new String []{"_id", "Name","Name2", "Date","title"},null, null, null, null,null);
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this, 
            R.layout.opp_main,  
            cursor, 
            new String[] {"Name", "Name2", "Date","title"}, 
            new int[] {R.id.firstName,R.id.total, R.id.title, R.id.accountname});

        cursor.moveToFirst();

        while(cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
            CloseDate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Date"));
            if(CloseDate.equals("30/09/2011 00:00")) {
                TextView cl = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);
                Log.d(tag, "cl: " +cl);
                Log.d(tag, "Date11111: " +Date);
                cl.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
            }

            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

I wanted to change the color of textview date which is storing in `R.id.title`.
here the log cat is giving null for the value cl.....and gives me nullpointer exception...:(
can any one tell me please.......?
thank you in advance...:)

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a View called `total` in the `opp_main.xml` file. Try adding it and see if that solves the issue.

Comment: Could you update the code in your question also include the stack trace you are getting from logcat?